# How do you take care of peach tree

Tags: peaches

How do I revive a Peachtree grove?

Comment: We'll need a lot more detail in order to help. For instance - how old is the grove? How many trees? Where in the US (I assume) are you - hardiness and heat zones, in particular? Why do you think you need to revive the grove - Dying trees? Diseased trees? If so, what are the symptoms? Problems with flowering? Problems with fruiting after adequate flowering? If no issues with flowering, what is the pollinator situation like in your area (where I live, pollinator numbers are way down from three years ago)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually by planting new trees, if you are attempting to "revive" an old peach orchard. You can attempt some fairly drastic pruning on the presumably overgrown trees, but expectations should be limited if the trees are not fairly young.

Peaches have a relatively short productive/economic lifespan, with most sources recommending replacement after 12-20 years in commercial production. That suggests that you may want to plan a rotation with trees of different ages to maintain consistent production.

https://www.hmcfarms.com/lifespan-of-a-peach-tree/

https://extension.psu.edu/peach-production

You may do better to plant your new peaches somewhere else, due to potential pest  problems when replanting where peaches were growing before, or wait a year or more, and treat for nematodes:

https://ucanr.edu/sites/cccoopext/files/80960.pdf