Why did my dads peach trees stop producing
My dad has 3 peach trees one is new 2 have been there and there used to be two others. I want to get back into gardening I used to help when I was a bumkin it’s cooling down in Mississippi so what should I do to now to help the trees produce, and what should I do to help when it gets warmer, I remember being a little girl and watching them bloom and blossom, and grow just the best peaches you could pull apart with your hands, I want my kids to have that joy too, also what other fruit trees could I plant to help or influence the best fruit (there use to be 4, 2 died a while back and I’m not sure if that is relevant I’m not to sure what killed them I was out of the house by then)

Pictures please or a good answer is very hard

Do you know what kind of peach trees?  What hardiness zone are you in?   (Peaches wont set fruit unless they have a certain number of chill hours).  Also, how old are the trees - Stone Fruit trees do have a lifespan.   Have the trees been pruned?

If it is just this year, it may be normal. Nature is unpredictable: rain on wrong week, and you may lost most/all fruit (but on a region with many peaches, it should be seldom). Also peaches are tricky to prune and unforgivable. Or just old and at end of life (happens often on grafter trees), or some disease... -- So we need photos to have better ideas.

Stock advice on peach trees is to replace them regularly for continued production. If you enjoyed them as a child, it's likely past time to plant a bunch of pits and grow some new trees. Peaches evidently come relatively true from seed, so (if they make any fruit now) your offspring can enjoy the fruit of the offspring of your dad's trees. See: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/65492/6806 Pollination (or lack therof) can also be a factor, so encourage or provide pollinators.
